# First scenario is failing every time in Scenario Outline in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara, site-prism

Whenever I run my Feature file with HTML report as output file, then 1st scenario in Scenario Outline is failing everytime. But when I make the same Scenario Outline as first Scenario in the Feature file it is getting passed, but this will make my test case flow weird in the Feature file.

Any idea why this is happening and how to overcome?

My Cucumber version is "1.3.15"

```
Scenario Outline: Validation of links
When I click "<Link>" link
Then I should be in the "<Link>" page

Examples:
  | Link          |
  | TV            |
  | Email         |
```

Comment: Can you copy-paste your scenario outline with Examples here ?

Comment: Updated Scenario outline with examples

Comment: Can you pls make sure you differentiate between 2 Links - You have 2 parameters in 2 steps and only one column

Comment: Both are of same parameters. I don't think we need to have 2 columns, as I am using same parameter in both the steps.